# aapt.exe crashes when using custom xmlns

Tags: android, xml-namespaces

I want to create a menu item that uses the ShareActionProvider of the Support V7 libraries.

As far as I understand, I need to create a custom xmlns in order to use XML attributes defined by the support library.

This is the code I'm using.

```
<menu xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="@string/menu_share"
        yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

My problem is that when I use this "yourapp" prefix within the menu item, aapt.exe crashes when it's trying to build. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Add `android:icon` with icon. Try to clean, rebuild.

Comment: I had already tried cleaning the project and didn't work. Now I tried with the icon and still not working.

Comment: I think there might be some issue with the namespace, because I don't have this problem if I remove the xmlns:yourapp and the atributes using this prefix.